# JPanels: the <div>s of the Java world?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Can JPanels be used in Java like `<div>`s get used in HTML? Is it ever consistent with good practice to have more than 1 JPanel in a JFrame for something other than CardLayout? (For example, if I had JPanel that contained a help/about button that was on the northern border of the content panel of the JFrame, and I used the one that contained the button to put some spacing in to force the button to be of a certain size...)

Specific case:

Suppose I am trying to make this: [image], and upon starting, I have a mock like this (thanks to some code for the button rendering I found elsewhere):  [image]. Would this case be good case to use multiple JFrames (like one would those HTML `<div>`s)? If not, when would be?

Comment: Yes, I guess. Depending on what you want to achieve, it's quite validate to have multiple panels within in a single container, and I often do for complex layouts

Comment: I'm about to get specific

Comment: Based on your updated ui, the answer is still yes and no. I could probably get your ui setup using a single panel and a `GridBagLayout`, but, multiple panels could help you provide more flexibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirements, you don't "have" to use multiple panels, you can accomplish what you want from a single panel and a `GridBagLayout`, for example...

[image: Single Panel]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            JButton helpButton = new JButton("?");
            JTextField projectDirectory = new JTextField(20);
            JTextField documentDirectory = new JTextField(20);
            JButton projectButton = new JButton("Project");
            JButton documentButton = new JButton("Document");
            JButton continueButton = new JButton("Continue to files");

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 1;

            add(new JLabel("Project Directory"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Documentation Directory"), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            add(projectDirectory, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(documentDirectory, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 2;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            add(helpButton, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(projectButton, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(documentButton, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            add(continueButton, gbc);
        }

    }

}
```

The main reasons I would use multiple panels is:

1. The layout was overly complex, it would allow me to break down the layout into individual requirements and focus more on the relationship between the groups
2. If I was focusing on separating the management into individual elements (such as the directory selection for example), where the panel could become a self contained unit of work, including the management and functionality, allowing to be a self contained and re-usable component

## Compound Panels...

[image: Multiple Components]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            JButton helpButton = new JButton("?");
            JButton continueButton = new JButton("Continue to files");

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            add(helpButton, gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new FolderSelectionPane("Project Folder"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new FolderSelectionPane("Documentation Folder"), gbc);
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(continueButton, gbc);
        }

    }

    public class FolderSelectionPane extends JPanel {

        public FolderSelectionPane(String label) {
            JTextField projectDirectory = new JTextField(20);
            JButton projectButton = new JButton("Folder");

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 2, 0, 2);
            add(new JLabel(label), gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            add(projectDirectory, gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            add(projectButton, gbc);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Initially, I did something like this. I just didn't carry it this far as I was building it row-by-row.

Comment: I might take that second approach, btw, as that help button might be shared throughout my project ( and one of your reasons is to separate individual elements ).